# Google Cloud DataStore runQuery is extremely slow for App Engine NodeJS app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, restify

I was just working on an reporting API which is built on top of DataStore, NodeJS Restify.

It was working great since the beginning but recently I saw a very troubling latency sometimes unbelievably higher latency and from Google Cloud Trace I did some sampling. See the following screenshot.

Based on this tracing, I figured out that most of my latency was due to DataStore runQuery call from **@google-cloud/datastore** package. So I am pretty disturbed about this. Note: I was just working on less than 500 datastore entity only.

So is there anything I can do to trace or any suggestion to investigate this issue?

**Google Cloud Project Info:**

- Region: us-central

**Query in NodeJS**
My query is simple. Here is a working snippet.
var datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')({
         projectId: '',
         keyFilename: '',
         namespace: ""
    });

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('my-key');

query.filter('email', '=', 'jondoe@example.com');
query.filter('gender', '=', 'male');

datastore.runQuery(query, function (err, entities) {
    console.log(err, entities);
})
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! I'm on the Datastore team and I'd like to know more so we can help. Can you tell me what region you're using and what kind of query it is?

Comment: @WillHayworth I am updating my question with these additional information.

Comment: @WillHayworth I just updated my questions with region and query.

Comment: any update on this?